# Vba project cant open if excel is already running

Tags: vba, excel

I want to open my vba project from my USB stick, but if excel is already running with some other sheets (with new data) it won't open my vba project.
It only opens when my other excel sheets are closed or saved. 
What can I do?
Is it possible to make a msgbox for telling the user that he must first save other excel projects (when I want to open the project while other excel sheets are not saved) ?

Answer (score 0):

Note that Excel allows a filename only once to be opened, independent of where the files are placed. So `C:\Documents\mysheets.xls` and `F:\memstick\mysheets.xls` have the same name and only one can be open at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to open a second Excel instance? 
1. Open Excel with start/programs/microsoft excel or wherever
2. Open your macro in that second instance or just pull it into that new excel form.

should work i think...

Comment: Thank you for your response, but that's not what I want.